# self.boolean_claas_value instance of a model doesnt store a value if its boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails project and I'm having trouble storing a boolean value. Works fine if its a string.

Here is a shorter version of the model

```rb
require 'active_record'

# Public: Class representing data
class RandomClass
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  # Public: Returns boolean hopefully
  attr_accessor :why_does_this_not_work

  def initialize(values = {})
    @why_does_this_not_work = values[:why_does_this_not_work]
  end

  def update_with(new_data)
    self.why_does_this_not_work = new_data.why_does_this_not_work || why_does_this_not_work
  end
```

When the value `why_does_this_not_work` is initialized it is set to a boolean but when the `update_with` is called with `new_data` although the value exists the assignment doesn't work.

`self.why_does_this_not_work = true` gets stored but when I do `self.why_does_this_not_work = new_data.why_does_this_not_work || why_does_this_not_work` or `self.why_does_this_not_work = new_data.why_does_this_not_work` the value doesn't get stored.

The same with `why_does_this_not_work`, the value gets stored when its initialized but it doesn't return anything when called.

All of the above works fine if a string is passed instead.

I'm assuming this maybe be something to do with boolean's in ruby. I tried to look at the class and the value comes back as `TrueClass` or `FalseClass`

Any help would be appreciated. I'm unsure if adding the controller code would play any role.

*Env:*

```json
Ruby: 2.6.2,
Rails: 5.2.4.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it not work when `new_data.why_does_this_not_work` is set to false? The `||` operator will disregard it if it's `false`.

```
false || true # => true
```

How about you try

```
def update_with(new_data)
  new_value = new_data.why_does_this_not_work.nil? ? why_does_this_not_work : new_data.why_does_this_not_work
  self.why_does_this_not_work = new_value
end
```

This will take whatever the value of `new_data` unless it's nil. It'll then fallback to the existing value.

Comment: I wish I made this post 2 days ago. Thank you. Ruby is a lot of magic that I'm trying to learn.